# Setting the initial value of a struct field to that of another in Go

Tags: struct, go, initialization

In Go, let's say I have this struct:

```
type Job struct {
    totalTime int
    timeToCompletion int
}
```

and I initialize a struct object like:

```
j := Job {totalTime : 10, timeToCompletion : 10}
```

where the constraint is that `timeToCompletion` is always equal to `totalTime` when the struct is created (they can change later). Is there a way to achieve this in Go so that I don't have to initialize both fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't avoid having to specify the value twice, but an idiomatic way would be to create a constructor-like creator function for it:

```
func NewJob(time int) Job {
    return Job{totalTime: time, timeToCompletion: time}
}
```

And using it you only have to specify the time value once when passing it to our `NewJob()` function:

```
j := NewJob(10)
```

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for such an idiom if there was no inbuilt way.